# Wordpress: Output custom user_meta data in registration notification

Tags: php, wordpress, output, customization

In WordPress, I have custom registration site for new users. Upon registration, there is an optional checkbox to subscribe to our newsletter. As far as I understand it, it adds the value of the checkbox to the user_meta table (the whole thing has been coded by a company in India, which I woould very much prefer to not involve again, since they delayed their work time and time again and didn't do good work after all).

The corresponding code snippet in my child theme's functions.php looks like this:

```
<?php echo '<div class="form-row form-row-wide">
<input type="checkbox" name="inter_offers" value="yes"> '; _e('I would like to subscribe to the Kurth Electronic newsletter.','kurth-child'); echo '<br></div>'; 
return $fields; ?>

add_action('woocommerce_created_customer','adding_extra_reg_fields');    
function adding_extra_reg_fields($user_id) {
extract($_POST);
update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_inter_offers',$inter_offers);
} ?>
```

(I have left out lines irrelevant to this issue.)

Now, this value is saved internally, but not displayed to me. I would like to show the value in an E-Mail or notification generated by WordPress when the user completes registration, so that we can manually add them to our newsletter list whenever someone chooses to subscribe to the newsletter. The problem is that I only have a limited knowledge of PHP and I don't know where to start.

I should also note that this is not done via the standard WorPress registration form, but by a WooCommerce registration form (I have disabled the standard WordPress registration for security reasons).

I tried using the "Better Notifications" plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/) for custom notifications whenever a new user completes their registration, but it ignores any php code that I add to the custom notifications body to display the user_meta data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not edit answers into the question. You're allowed by Stack Overflow to answer your own question, and you will even be able to accept it. To keep the separation of question and answer clear, please post your solution as an answer instead of as an edit to the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because the registration is done via woocomerce you may have to look for a notification PlugIN that works with woocomerce, the one you have may just work properly with wordpress core version!

You also could generate a mail via php in the function, so that you get a message with the user mail adress, but i think without php knowledge it is not that easy to use the built in php mailer... (You may need an api there!)

But wouldn't it be better to automatically sign them into your newsletter software? For example for Mailchimp or other systems like that there are quite good wordpress plugins!

You may also be able to include the forms of these PlugIns in your registration form, but without a closer look at this woocomerce registration i can't tell for sure!

Comment: I was able to output default user data in custom notification generated via the plugin, so it should work. The problem that I have with the plugin is that it does not accept custom php code to output data from custom user_meta fields.

Generating the mail in the function.php is a good idea - do you recommend a certain tutorial or resource for that? I can still decide later if that's too complicated for me. ;)

As for the Email software, we use one that does not really work with other systems. We have to enter new data manually.

Comment: I correct myself, it seems to be quite easy by just using the mail function... I remebered a case where I had to generate a html mail and read that it might be complicated to set up the mail content correctly, so I used a small api that parsed the mail for me...
But in this case you just need the user mail as content if the custom field is checked, so it should be no problem, take look here:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

If you experience problems just google "php mailer" that api may help you and you will find a lots of tutorials!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick, it will notify you every time a new user is created and also tell you if they subscribed or not.

```
function new_customer_registered_send_email_admin($user_login, $user_email) {
    ob_start();
    do_action('woocommerce_email_header', 'New customer registered');
    $email_header = ob_get_clean();
    ob_start();
    do_action('woocommerce_email_footer');
    $email_footer = ob_get_clean();

    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $user_email );
    $subscribed = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'billing_inter_offers', true );

    woocommerce_mail(
        get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
        get_bloginfo('name').' - New customer registered',
        $email_header.'<p>The user '.esc_html( $user_login ).' created an account ' . ( $subscribed ? ' and subscribed to the newsletter.' : '.' ) . '<br>Email:'.esc_html( $user_email ).'</p>'.$email_footer
    );
}

add_action('new_customer_registered', 'new_customer_registered_send_email_admin', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! Unfortunately, it does not seem to get executed upon registering test users. No Email is sent and the debug logfile does not show errors related to those lines of code. I placed the code right after the one mentioned in my original post - maybe I have to put it somewhere else?

Comment: Is the code executing at all?  Embed a log statement in the code somewhere to make sure it's executing error_log( 'code is executing' );  Also comment out the old code action for now.

Comment: I have tried adding the code, but it either did not do anything (no new entry in the log file) or broke the site because of a syntax error. Where exactly should I put it?

Comment: I now managed to execute the code - as it turned out, my customer-new-account.php was missing the following line of code:
`<?php do_action( 'new_customer_registered', $user_login ); ?>`
Adding that triggered the function established with your code. However, the email only contains the username, an empty email field and does not indicate if the user has checked the newsletter box, which is the  point in the first case.

Comment: Save the checkbox value for the newsletter to the user_meta table.  Then when you send an email you can check if they ticked the box or not and send the email with that data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the plugin [amr users](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-users/) to generate a userlist of all users who had a certain metadata tag set to a certain value (in my case, if they want to recieve a newsletter - the previous developers never bothered to make the data actually readable without extra effort). It is a little clunky to use and not what I originally intended, but it got the job done.